# Modify the action of a class depending on a option in a another class?

Tags: java

This is a question about style. What is the cleanest solution to this case:

I have a Runnable class:

```
class R implements Runnable {
  public void run(){
    System.out.print("hello")
  }
}
```

And another class that starts this class like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new R());
t.start;
```

My question is that if i need run to do something a bit more different depending on an radio button selected in the class that starts the thread what would be the best way to pass it on to the Runnable class?

Should i just make a constructor and add a Boolean witch action to perform? Or make a public boolean and set it to true false before running the thread? Or should i define an Enum in R class with the different actions and pass it on? Or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree that the best way is for the Runnable's constructor to accept whatever parameters are required for execution.  For example:

```
class R implements Runnable {

  private final boolean myBool;

  public R(boolean myBool) {
    this.myBool = myBool;
  }

  public void run(){
    if (myBool) {
      System.out.print("hello");
    } else {
      System.out.print("goodbye");
    }
  }
}
```

In general, making public global variables (the other alternative you've mentioned) is bad practice.  The method listed above ensures encapsulation; only the things that need to know about the value know about it.  This ensures that as your system grows more complex, no other classes are messing up your values :-)